# swapping numbers in a list is equivalent to remove & reinsert?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, local-search

Given some ordered list of $n$ items, I obviously have $n!$ possible arrangements. However, as a heuristic in some larger algorithm that needs to find the optimal order, I want to do some quick local exploration. One option is to walk through all possible removal & insert operations at $O(n(n-1))$. A similar option is to run through all possible 2-swaps (e.g 2-opts), also at a cost of $O(n(n-1))$. The question: do those two heuristic approaches cover the same solution set? Are they equivalent?

Comment: No, simply because $[1,2,3]$ can be transformed to $[3,1,2]$ using the first but not the second method. (Just check all possible swaps.)

Comment: @plshelp, that sounds like a nice answer to the question!  I encourage you to write it in the answer box, rather than as a comment, so we can upvote it and so the question counts as answered.  We discourage answering the question in the comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, simply because $[1,2,3]$ can be transformed to $[3,1,2]$ using one insertion but not using one swap. Just check all possible swaps to prove this.